# how to check if it is the last line of a string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

i have a loop that extracts the string from a textbox line by line i want to have a condition if its the last line i will store it in another textbox. here is my code

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
Dim reader As New StringReader(txtOCR.Text)

While True
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit While

        Dim WordCount = New Regex("\w+").Matches(line).Count

        If WordCount = 1 And Not line.ToLower().Contains("by") Then
            builder.AppendLine(line)

        ElseIf line.ToLower().Contains("the") And Not line.ToLower().Contains("by") Then
            builder.AppendLine(line)

        ElseIf line.ToLower().Contains("an") And Not line.ToLower().Contains("by") Then
            builder.AppendLine(line)
        End If
End While
txtTitle.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter inside the loop and then:

```
If iCounter = txtOCR.Lines.Length Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: another question how to check if lines are separated by big space? thank you

Comment: @user2107624 It would be better if you add another different question.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the `string` variable `'Line'` in each `iteration` of the `while loop` to the particular `text box`. It will replace the text in each `iterations` and finally it will produce the result matching your expectation.

```
While True

        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit While

        ....................
        ....................

        txtNew.text = line 'Assigning the variable to the separate text box

End While
```